# Books on continuity(need very much)

Tags: continuity, book-recommendation

Suggest books,which are full of limit and continuity solved problems,in undergraduate level.(real analysis)

Answer (score 1):

Walter Rudin's mathematical analysis
Also Thomas Calculus

Comment: Rudin's Principles doesn't come with solved problems to exercises in the book.

Comment: There's a suggested solution manual, although not so encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

For introductory real analysis Numbers and Functions: Steps into Analysis by R. P. Burn.

For real and complex analysis from the metric space point of view A Second Course In Mathematical Analysis by J. C. Burkill.

Both books come with solutions to almost every exercise.

Disclaimer: I am in the process of reading Burn's book and recommend Burkill's book based on Burn's recommendation of it in the bibliography.